# How does one determine the containing boundary of a fractal?

Tags: fractals

In the Mandelbrot set, the fractal is said to be contained in the circle of radius 2.
$$
    z_{n+1} = {z_{n}}^{2} + c 
$$
I did read about a proof that showed values of 'c' beyond this circle are not bounded and hence the set is contained within.

But say if someone discovers a new set that generates a fractal, How does one determine the containing boundary of that fractal ?

PS: I have studied basic engineering Mathematics and learning fractals on my own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to calculate a lot of points and find which points stay finite and distinguish points that take a long time to go to infinity from points that take a short time. Basically use a computer, then look at the result. Also its a fractal, so the boundary can't be determined, it would have infinite points in it. You could approximate it however, use different colors for different escape times.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that. But I'm referring to the bailout/escape value.

Comment: Every c with an absolute value above 2 is good start.

Answer (score 1):

(I gave the answer above as well) Given the lack of answers to your question I'll link you to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1209112/taylor-series-of-mandelbrot-bulb-boundaries). It should give you more than you can handle, which is why I refrained, I barely understand it myself, but hey maybe I'm projecting. It'll answer all of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

One can you geometric algorithms like [boundary checking ( Sobel filter)](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:A_parabolic_checkerboard_for_rotation_number_1_over_2.png)